# American au pair. What visa do I need?

Tags: visas

I am an American au pair. The family I will be staying with is going on a holiday in Spain and they are from Italy. What visa should I have in order to go with them and be allowed back into Italy?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. To clarify: you are a U.S. citizen working as an au pair in Italy, and are asking what visas you would need to accompany the family to Spain?

Comment: Are you working in Italy or in USA right now? If in Italy, what visa do you have?

Comment: Will you be working when in Spain or will it be leisure time for you?

Comment: hi @Willeke - it is almost inconceivable anyone would require her to have a working visa for that, although it's an interesting detail!

Comment: She should have a working visa if required to work in Spain, the family might try to get away with it if they give her 'time off' officially but still require her to do some work.

Comment: What visa are you currently on in Italy?

Comment: @Fattie: It happens, depending on the rules around working in the country in question. Doing that in NZ instead of Spain could get her in trouble, see here for a related story: [Immigration New Zealand changing practices after au pair locked up](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=11694693)

Comment: right on @GregHewgill .  Italy -> Spain , wouldn't be an issue

Comment: Wrong. Tourist visa cover all of Schengen, work visa are per country and working in an other country from where you have your visa is not allowed and if caught will get you in trouble. Whether they catch you is up to chance, they are not likely to unless something happens that brings the family or au pair in contact with the police for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes, just as you say it is ***incredibly*** unlikely. The zillions of times we've wandered around Europe (with au-pairs) (au-pair?) (au-pairren?  :) ) It is just incredibly unlikely this would happen, and they are "not working" anyway, it's "a break" for the ladies.